# Are bz files different from bz2 and how to make bz files instead of bz2?

Tags: bzip2

Are bz files different from .bz2? I'm guessing bz2 is the successor of bz and perhaps they use different compression algorithms or are they essentially suffixes of filenames that mean the same thing?

bzip2(1) apparently doesn't mention the difference between bz and bz2 files, it does however mention this:

> bunzip2 (or bzip2 -d) decompresses all specified files.  Files which were not created by bzip2 will be detected and ignored, and a warning issued.
>
> bzip2  attempts
>          to  guess  the filename for the decompressed file from that of the compressed file
>          as follows:
>
> ```
>     filename.bz2    becomes   filename
>       filename.bz     becomes   filename
>       filename.tbz2   becomes   filename.tar
>       filename.tbz    becomes   filename.tar
>       anyothername    becomes   anyothername.out
> ```

*Are bz files different from bz2 files and if so how to make bz files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different. `bzip2` was a re-written version of `bzip`, re-worked to avoid potential patent issues with the original `bzip`. The [old homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/19980704181204/http://www.muraroa.demon.co.uk/) has details:

> bzip2 is a rewritten and re-engineered version of 0.21. It looks superficially fairly similar, but has been almost entirely re-written (several times :-). The important differences are:
>
> - Patent-free!  (I hope; see statement above). bzip-0.21 used arithmetic coding; bzip2 uses Huffman coding, which is generally regarded as non-problematic from a patent standpoint. Both programs are based on the Burrows-Wheeler transform, but, to the best of my knowledge, that's not patented either.
> - Faster, particularly at decompression. bzip2 decompresses more than 50% faster than 0.21, mostly because of the use of Huffman coding. I've also improved the compression speed, although not that much -- perhaps it compresses 30% faster than 0.21.
> - Recovery from media errors. Both programs compress data in blocks, by default, 900k long. With bzip2, each block is handled completely independently, carries its own checksum, and is delimited by a 48-bit sequence. So, if you have a damaged compressed file, bzip2 can extract the compressed blocks, detect which ones are undamaged, and decompress those.
> - Test mode. You can test integrity of compressed files without having to decompress them. I should have put this in 0.21, really, but was too lazy (+ burnt-out with hacking by the time I released it).
> - Handles very repetitive files much better. Such files are a worst-case for any block-sorting compressor. bzip2 runs approximately ten times faster than 0.21 for such files.
> - Support for smaller machines. bzip2 can decompress any file it creates in 2300k, which means you can decompress files on 4-meg machines. Peak memory use during compression is also reduced by about 900k compared with 0.21, to around 6400k.
> - Better flag handling. In particular, long flags (--like --this) are supported, which makes it easier to use.
> - The one-line startup message which 0.21 printed, is gone. This was 0.21's most complained-about feature. It even bugs *me* nowadays.

To make `bz` files, you need to get the old `bzip` compressor and use that. There’s no real reason to do so...